# How to embed tomcat in the application and run by java -jar command

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-plugin, tomcat8

My application is soap web services that is packaged as `war file` and is put it in webapp folder of tomcat to deploy so I googled how to build the java executable-jar-file with tomcat embedded but I did not the suitable document.

I want to build my project by `mvn clean package` and run the application by `java -jar` instead of build it as war file and put it in webapp folder of tomcat to deploy it

The structure of my project:

the web.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JAXWSServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAXWSServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/core/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

sun-jaxws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
    <endpoint
            name="MessageRelayService"
            implementation="com.messagerelay.ws.interactive.MessageRelay"
            url-pattern="/core/MessageRelayService"/>
</endpoints>
```

and the part of WS java file:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://webservice.net/", serviceName = "MessageRelayService")
@BindingType(value = SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class MessageRelay {
```

Comment: What did you Google [search] for? There are tons of examples online for how to do this. Maybe you just aren't looking for the right terms.

Comment: If it is, please answer the question